# Trying to figure out the password for my IP Camera using Hydra

Tags: hydra

I have a client who has an IP camera, and I'm trying to crack the password using Hydra. It seems to have cracked the password, but when I try logging into it, the username and password dialogue keeps popping up over and over. Here's what I did:

```
root@kali:~# hydra -l root -P '/root/Documents/top100pass' -e ns -f -V xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx http-get /
```

And then, here are the results.

```
[DATA] max 16 tasks per 1 server, overall 64 tasks, 100003 login tries (l:1/p:100003), ~97 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get on port 80
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "root" - 1 of 100003 [child 0]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "" - 2 of 100003 [child 1]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "123456" - 3 of 100003 [child 2]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "password" - 4 of 100003 [child 3]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "12345678" - 5 of 100003 [child 4]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "qwerty" - 6 of 100003 [child 5]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "123456789" - 7 of 100003 [child 6]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "12345" - 8 of 100003 [child 7]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "1234" - 9 of 100003 [child 8]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "111111" - 10 of 100003 [child 9]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "1234567" - 11 of 100003 [child 10]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "dragon" - 12 of 100003 [child 11]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "123123" - 13 of 100003 [child 12]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "baseball" - 14 of 100003 [child 13]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "abc123" - 15 of 100003 [child 14]
[ATTEMPT] target xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - login "root" - pass "football" - 16 of 100003 [child 15]
[80][http-get] host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   login: root
[STATUS] attack finished for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx valid pair found)

1 of 1 target successfully completed, 1 valid password found

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2017-03-20 09:38:21"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You found a valid pair and the web page has an error?

Comment: it's also possible that the error on the page made hydra think the credential pair was valid when it is not

Comment: The thing that says "valid pair found" and "1 of 1 target successfully completed, 1 valid password found" made me think that it had found the password. It's an Axis camera, so I know that the login is "root". I'm curious why it's saying it's found a password when it clearly hasn't. Also, I've used Hydra on a couple of other security cameras, and it did find and display a user name and password, but when I entered the user name and password found, it just prompted me again for the user name and password. Has anyone been able to use Hydra sucessfully?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behaviour when hydra is not configured properly to determine when a credential pair is successful. If you search on this site for the tag "hydra", you will find many, many others with a similar problem.

Comment: I appreciate the response schroeder. I'll look into it.